# Angular JS ui-router opening the page by direct url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I link to the profile pages with the code below:

```
<p ui-sref="app.profile({profileKey:form.profileKey})">{{form.profileName}}</p>
```

Whenever a user clicks the link the my routing runs:

```
function config($stateProvider)
{
    // State
    $stateProvider
        .state('app.profile', {
            url      : '/profile/:profileKey',
            views    : {
                'content@app': {
                    profileKey: 'pages/profile/profile.html',
                    controller : 'profileController as vm'
                }
            },
            resolve  : {
                profileKey: function ($stateParams)
                {
                    return ($stateParams.profileKey);
                }
            },
            bodyClass: 'profile'
        });
}
```

No problem with my link and code. But how can I reach the profile pages by writing the direct url on browser. 
I want it to be reachable when you write for example: "http://www.myapp.com/profile/lionelmessi" and then reading that **"lionelmessi"** value on my page controller.js

But now it shows `"Cannot GET /profile/lionelmessi"` message on browser

I mean the same thing which twitter or facebook does on their profile pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

More information [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

Answer (score 0):

If you aren´t using html5Mode as @Vitalii suggests you need to use the hash character to separate your app hostname and basepath from the route part in the URL:

Something like this:

http://www.myapp.com/#/profile/lionelmessi

But if you are using or want to use html5mode remember that you need:

1)

```js
function config($stateProvider, $locationProvider)
{
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true
  });

  //your $stateProvider config
}
```

2) have some rewrite rule in your server side

This is because your need that your index.html handles every request for your site/app. That server side code depends on the platform your are gonna deploy your app. Apache (PHP), IIS (.net), etc.

3) Add the base tag in the HEAD of your index.html

```html
<base href="/">
```

- The simple way is not going html5mode and use the hashbang in the url unless you really need to.